# string_view return broken in g++ 9.3.0?

Tags: c++, c++17

In the below code, the string_view value in callee is per design. But after it returns to the caller, it is wrong. The two address are different so it doesn't seem return elision is working. If not, I'd expect at least string_view copy c'tor should work but it doesn't either.

```
static string_view my_to_string_view(uint32_t value)
{
  std::array<char, 10> str;
  if (auto [ptr, ec] = std::to_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), value); ec == std::errc())
  {
    cout << "data:" << str.data() << "\n";
    cout << "length is:" << ptr - str.data()<<"\n";
    auto ret = std::string_view(str.data(), ptr - str.data()); // C++17, uses string_view(ptr, length);
    cout << "return value in func:" << ret << "\n";
    return ret;
  }

  throw std::exception();
}

int main()
{
  std::string_view s = my_to_string_view(125);
  std::cout << "return value in main is:"<< s <<"\n";
}

data:125%%�
length is:3
return value in func:125
return value in main is:
```

Comment: btw, the line `cout << "data:" << str.data()` is problematic because the array is not null-terminated. Hence the `'%%�'` at the end of the output.

Answer (score 5):

You're returning a string view that references a local variable. The `string_view` is fine, but the data it "points to" (i.e, part of the array `str`) no longer exists.

See [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) for more information about `string_view`

Comment: Wouldn't return cause copy constructor to called and copy the actual data? If what you said is true, then if one needs to return string_view, it needs to be created on the heap always?

Comment: A `string_view` does not contain the actual data (use `string` for that), it just holds a pointer and a length. *Those* get copied by the copy constructor. And no, the data it refers to doesn't need to be created on the heap always, but its lifetime needs to be longer than the `string_view`. (and the heap is a fine place for that)